# Rails model act as another entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have model Organization. It can be the user's company or it can be a client company.

So when creating an invoice, I need to set organization_id (the user's company) and a client_id (it's an id from the organization table, but now acting as a client).

How can I set this up? I still have no Client model setup.

**Details added**

Both the organization_id and the client_id are pulled from the Organizations table. So for example...

INVOICES

- organization_id (this mean the invoice was created BY this
  organization)
- client_id (this means the invoice was created FOR that
  organization)

But both of those ids are making reference to the same organizations table.

Answer (score 0):

```
belongs_to :organization
belongs_to :client, :class_name => 'Organization'
```